# Github Actions Build for iOS Failing

Tags: swift, xcode, build, github-actions, action

I am new to Github actions and I was trying to make an action to attempt a build and see if the build passes or fails an Xcode iOS build but I keep getting the error

```
line 1: cd: Swift/: No such file or directory
6
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
name: Xcode build iOS 14

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-11

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Select Xcode
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_13.3.app

    - name: Xcode version
      run: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

    - name: Xcode build
      run: |
        cd Swift/
        xcodebuild clean build -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.4'
```

Comment: As in error: Swift folder doesn't exist - apparently you don't have Swift folder in your repository...

Answer (score 0):

I would try `cd Swift` instead of `cd Swift/` , if you have Swift folder in your project.